# Can I change the environment on a per-process basis on Windows (like on Unix)?

Tags: windows-7, windows, command-line, environment-variables

On Unix operative systems I can start a process with additional environment variables like this:

```
$ DEBUG=1 VERBOSE=3 python myscript.py
```

Does the Windows CMD have an equivalent for this? I'm stuck developing on a Windows computer and I want to test release-behaviour without having to build the project or permanently change the env variables in my CMD session.

Answer (score 5):

You'd need to wrap your command in a batch file and then use `setlocal` in it:

```
setlocal
Set DEBUG=1
Set VERBOSE=1
python myscript.py
```

`Setlocal` makes all variable definition/changes local to that batch file.

Edit: You may use `setlocal/endlocal` to localize a single command, or set of commands in batch, **but it does not work outside of batch**. Full description of [setlocal/endlocal](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/setlocal.mspx?mfr=true)

Answer (score 3):

The closest thing you can get is the SET command.
This is not a permanent command, and will revert when you open a new CMD session.

Example: SET variable=string

http://ss64.com/nt/set.html

Comment: +1 That's cool, but it's not really equivalent of the Unix example. I want to set environment variables for one process, but SET changes the environment for the console.